How to return a mock from a mock in testify/mock with Golang?
Is it possible to return mock structs on mock calls?
// Mocks
type mockStorage struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *mockStorage) Bucket(bucket string) *storage.BucketHandle {
    args := m.Called(bucket)
    return args.Get(0).(*storage.BucketHandle)
}

type mockBucketHandle struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *mockBucketHandle) Object(name string) *storage.ObjectHandle {
    args := m.Called(name)
    return args.Get(0).(*storage.ObjectHandle)
}

// Test
func TestStorageClient_LoadChangelog(t *testing.T) {
    // Given
    logger := zerolog.New(os.Stdout).With().Timestamp().Logger()
    zerolog.DefaultContextLogger = &logger
    bucketHandleMock := &mockBucketHandle{}
    bucketHandleMock.On("Object", mock.Anything).Return(&storage.ObjectHandle{})
    storageMock := &mockStorage{}
    storageMock.On("Bucket", mock.Anything).Return(bucketHandleMock)
    client := NewStorageClient(storageMock)

    // When
    handle := client.getObjectHandle(uuid.NewString())
    
    // Then 
    assert.NotNil(t, handle)
}

And the code I am trying to test:
func (s *StorageClient) getObjectHandle(url string) *storage.ObjectHandle {
    bucket, name := urlToBucketAndName(url)
    return s.Client.Bucket(bucket).Object(name)
}

And the error — not entirely unexpected:
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is *sclient.mockBucketHandle, not *storage.BucketHandle [recovered]


Probably the easiest fix is going to be returning interfaces from Bucket() and Object(). Then the real implementation continues to return *storage.Bucket and *storage.Object, respectively, and returning e.g. *mockBucketHandle will also work if it implements the interface.

This isn't S3 bucket and object using Go SDK for AWS, is it?  They recommend and support (to the extent required) what Gavin suggests

It's GCS (Google), but probably applies as well. Not entirely sure how to modify the return signature, though.
Cannot use googleStorageClient (type *Client) as the type GoogleStorageInterface Type does not implement GoogleStorageInterface need the method: Bucket(bucket string) BucketHandleInterface have the method: Bucket(name string) *BucketHandle```

The solution required some refactoring. In essence, I needed to wrap the original types into my mockable types.
type googleStorageClient struct {
    client *storage.Client
}

type googleStorageBucketHandle struct {
    handle *storage.BucketHandle
}

type GoogleStorageInterface interface {
    Bucket(name string) GoogleStorageBucketHandleInterface
}

type GoogleStorageBucketHandleInterface interface {
    Object(name string) *storage.ObjectHandle
}

func (g *googleStorageClient) Bucket(name string) GoogleStorageBucketHandleInterface {
    return &googleStorageBucketHandle{handle: g.client.Bucket(name)}
}

func (g *googleStorageBucketHandle) Object(name string) *storage.ObjectHandle {
    return g.handle.Object(name)
}

This then allowed me to use mocks as I posted above.
